Inconsistencies in modeling a binary variable that indicates a switch
this is a follow-up question to this post here and to @RobPratt's answer. I have implemented the whole thing, and now it happened that on day 1 the machine did not run and was only used for the first time on day 2, but a shift change was modeled, even though there was actually none. What could be the reason for this and how do I have to adjust the constraints to prevent this from happening? That is the answer:
\begin{align}
\rho_{ptm} &\le 1-s_{ptm} &&\text{for all $p,t,m$} \\
\rho_{ptm} &\le d_{ptm} &&\text{for all $p,t,m$} \\
\rho_{ptm} &\ge d_{ptm} - s_{ptm} &&\text{for all $p,t,m$}\\
\sum_m d_{ptm} + x_{pt} &= 1 &&\text{for all $p,t$} \\
s_{p,t+1,m} &= d_{ptm} + y_{ptm} &&\text{for all $p,t\not=T,m$} \\
y_{ptm} &\le s_{ptm} &&\text{for all $p,t,m$} \\
y_{ptm} &\le x_{pt} &&\text{for all $p,t,m$} \\
y_{ptm} &\ge s_{ptm} + x_{pt} - 1 &&\text{for all $p,t,m$}
\end{align}
The variables are defined as:

$d_{ptm}$: Binary variable indicating if product $p$ was serviced by machine $m$ in period $t$
$\rho_{ptm}$: Binary variable indicating if there was a switch in machines for product $p$ in period $t$ to machine $m$
$s_{ptm}$: State variable indicating if the last servicing of product $p$ prior to period $t$ was by machine $m$
$y_{ptm}$: Auxiliary variable to assist in defining constraints related to $s_{ptm}$ and $x_{pt}$
$x_{pt}$: Binary variable indicating if product $p$ is not being serviced in period $t$

And that is the original question:

I have the following question / concern. I have a modeling problem
with the decision variable $d_{ptm}$ which indicates whether product
$p$ was serviced by machine $m$ in period $t$. It takes the value 1 if
so, and 0 otherwise. A product can be serviced by different machine in
different periods. In addition, a product may not be serviced for two
days and then again, possibly by a different machine.  I now want to
introduce a binary variable $\rho$ that indicates such a switch in
machines a product was serviced by. It should take the value = 1 if
there was a machine switch from the last time a product was serviced
till the current period. How can I model this?


Please add to your question the definition of every variable.

As mentioned in the comments to the linked question, there is some ambiguity about a switch for the first servicing.  Is there anything in the rest of your model that encourages switches?

I'm going to assume that time indexing starts at 1. You can introduce a new binary variable $\gamma_{p,t}$ together with the constraints $$\gamma_{p,1}=1$$ $$\gamma_{p,t} \le \gamma_{p, t-1}$$ $$\gamma_{p,t} \le x_{p,t-1}$$ and $$\gamma_{p,t} \ge \gamma_{p,t-1} + x_{p,t-1} - 1.$$ Collectively this ensures that $\gamma_{p,t}=1$ if and only if $p$ has not been in production (on any machine) prior to time $t.$
Now adjust your first and third constraints as follows: $$\rho_{p,t,m}\le 1-s_{p,t,m}-\gamma_{p,t}$$ $$\rho_{p,t,m} \ge d_{p,t,m}-s_{p,t,m} - \gamma_{p,t}.$$

Dear @prubin. Thank you for your anwser. Does this also hold, if $d_{p1m} = 1 \forall p,m$ is true. So does it work if a machine is active on day 1 or not? Could you maybe explain how this works? Doesnt $\gamma_{p,1}=1$ force the machine to be not in production? As you stated in your anwser?

The first three inequalities I listed apply for $t>1$ (so that $t-1$ is meaningful). Yes, it works if the machine is active on day 1. $\gamma_{p,1}=1$ implies that the machine was not in production prior to day 1 (which it cannot be, since day 1 is the first day of the time horizon).

Thanks. I misread that. One final question. With your two lower constraints (the modified ones), they originate from the product $\rho_{ptm}=(1-s_{ptm})d_{ptm}$. What would the non-linear formulation of the modification look like? And I guess the constraints 2-4 from you could also be compromised to $\gamma_{pt}=\gamma_{pt}\cdot x_{pt}$. Correct?

Final answer(s); I assume you mean $\gamma_{p,t}=\gamma_{p,t-1}\cdot x_{p,t},$ which would be equivalent to my constraints 2-4. The nonlinear definition of $\rho$ would be $\rho_{ptm}=(1-s_{ptm}-\gamma_{pt})d_{ptm}.$
